# Xcode Swift 3 ~ Make speed into an integer

Tags: swift, xcode, performance

I understand that Int() is how to make something and integer but this doesn't work when using it with speed. Here is my code:

```
    var speed: CLLocationSpeed = CLLocationSpeed()
    speed = location.speed * 2.23694


    if location.speed < 1 {
        speedLabel.text = "0"
    }
    else {
        speedLabel.text = "\(speed)"
    }
```

Just wondering how to make my speed (mph) into an integer because currently I am getting 2 decimal points which make my app look messy. Thanks in advance

Comment: "this doesn't work when using it with speed", what do you mean with that? Does it give you an error?

Answer (score 0):

Use a rounding function.  In action:

```
 22> round (1.6)
$R10: Double = 2
 23> Int(round (1.6))
$R11: Int = 2
```